# Using RX to communicate between two components through a mediator

Tags: design-patterns, system.reactive, rx-java

C1 and C2 are components that don't know about each other. C1 does things that C2 cares about. I use a "Manager/Mediator" to allow communication between them.

Both C1 and C2 reference this mediator. C1 calls method `mMediator.notifyItemProduced()` and `Mediator` forwards an 'onItemProduced' event to any listener it has. C2 implements this listener interface and does what it wants with it.

```
class Mediator {
   List<Listener> mListeners;

   public void notifyItemProduced() {
        for each listener in mListeners
            listener.onItemProduced();
   }

   public void addListener(Listener listener) { ... }

   public interface Listener { 
       void onItemProduced();
   }
}

class C1 {
    public void onClick() { mMediator.notifyItemProduced(); }
}

class C2 {
    public C2 { mMediator.addListener(this); }

    public void onItemProduced() { 
        // do something here!
    }
}
```

I'm evaluating replacing this pattern with an RX implementation. I'm thinking that the `Mediator` should hold on to a `Subject` that C1 publishes to and C2 subscribes to.

```
class Mediator {
   Subject<Boolean, Boolean> mItems;

   public Subject<Boolean, Boolean> getItemsSubject() {
        return mItems;
   }

   public Observable<Booelan> getItemsStream() {
       return mItems.asObservable();
   }
}

class C1 {
    public void onClick() { mMediator.getItemsSubject().onNext(true); }
}

class C2 {
    public C2 { mMediator.getItems().subscribe(b => doSomething(b)); }
}
```

I don't like that the `Mediator` exposes to everyone the ability to publish events. Though I know this ability existed in the listener-based implementation, I'd like to know if there's a pattern that would allow:

- C1 & C2 not knowing about each other
- Only C1 can publish events
- Anyone can subscribe to these events

Or is what I have a reasonable/best solution?

Comment: What's the responsibility for the mediator other that to pass thru the values? Does it manage who can produce and who can consume? Or is it a dumb-mediator? Or something else?

Comment: In my context, the Mediator is an object making data requests and storing state. The components are views. It doesn't currently manage who *can* produce or consume, as it allows anyone to notify that an item has been produced, and allows anyone to add itself as a listener.

Comment: I would then suggest that the mediator has a `IDisposable Publish(IObservable source)` method and a `IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver destination)` method. That way the mediator is tracking both incoming and outgoing values and can manage errors. Otherwise you're better off not having a long lasting mediator and just connect observables directly to observers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve your current solution, I would replace the `Mediator.getItemsSubject()` with `Mediator.publishValue( T value )` in order to

- Abstract the communication (*the message publisher does not need to know how it is done*)
- Gain some control on what is published
- Not to hand over the `Subject` to wrong hands

---

If you really need that only `C1` should be allowed to publish messages: Have your `C1` signal in *events*, `Mediator` could register `C1` objects as *publishers* and emit `Observable` values based on `C1` events with e.g. `Observable.FromEventPattern`. Now, your interface could look like this.

```
interface Mediator {
    void AddPublisher(C1 pub);
    void RemovePublisher(C1 pub);
    Observable<bool> GetItemsStream();
}
```

(pardon my C# :)